# Azure Service Bus and Azure Function Queue Trigger

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an issue to create an `Azure Function` with `Queue Trigger` in .NET core 2.0.

### What I want

In a `microservice` architecture, when a new message is created in a queue for creating a user, a service has to receive this message and creates a user in a database based on the information in it.

### Issue

In Visual Studio 2017 I create a new project under `Azure Function`.

[image: Visual Studio Add New Project]

From the **New Template** I select `Queue Trigger`.

[image: Visual Studio New Template]

This screen is different from a [Microsoft post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/) about this subject. Anyway, first issue is what `Connection` and `Path` are.

I created a `Service Bus` and I have my credential from `Azure Portal`. I copied `Primary Connection String` and `Path` is the name of my queue.

If I run the project, I receive a lot of errors. I found this link on `Azure Documentation` for a [simple trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger-sample). In this example they use `ServiceBusTrigger` instead of `QueueTrigger`. For resolving `ServiceBusTrigger`, I added `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` from Nuget. It seems it doesn't work.

[image: Azure Portal Service Bus]

To have the right credential for my `Azure Function`, I created one in `Azure Portal` and downloaded the `app content`.

[image: Azure Portal Function]

It looks like

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "beta",
    "ScmType": "None",
    "WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED": "False",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my;AccountKey=something",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "6.5.0",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=my;AccountKey=something",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "createprofile-98873b60",
    "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "CreateProfile",
    "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME": "Production",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=createprofil8796;AccountKey=something"
  },
  "configurationSource": "config",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "connection": "sb://myservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=something",
      "queueName": "testqueue",
      "accessRights": "manage",
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the error page I have

[image: Error Page]

> Warning: Cannot find value named
>   'https://MyDevServiceBus.servicebus.windows.net' in
>   local.settings.json that matches 'connection' property set on
>   'queueTrigger' in
>   'C:\Projects\CustomerProfile.AzureService\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Function1\function.json'.
>   You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings
>   ' or specify a connection string in
>   local.settings.json. [12/03/2018 12:10:41] Reading host configuration
>   file
>   'C:\Projects\CustomerProfile.AzureService\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
>   [12/03/2018 12:10:41] Host configuration file read: [12/03/2018
>   12:10:41] { [12/03/2018 12:10:41] } [12/03/2018 12:10:42] Generating 1
>   job function(s) [12/03/2018 12:10:42] Starting Host
>   (HostId=desktop7fksikf-631144646, Version=2.0.11353.0, ProcessId=8992,
>   Debug=False, Attempt=0, FunctionsExtensionVersion=beta) Listening on
>   http://localhost:7071/ Hit CTRL-C to exit... [12/03/2018 12:10:42] A
>   ScriptHost error has occurred [12/03/2018 12:10:42]
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK
>   'QueueConnection' connection string is missing or empty. The Microsoft
>   Azure Storage account connection string can be set in the following
>   ways: [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 1. Set the connection string named
>   'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection' in the connectionStrings section of the
>   .config file in the following format , or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 2. Set the environment variable named
>   'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection', or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 3. Set
>   corresponding property of JobHostConfiguration. [12/03/2018 12:10:42]
>   Error indexing method 'Function1.Run' [12/03/2018 12:10:42]
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK
>   'QueueConnection' connection string is missing or empty. The Microsoft
>   Azure Storage account connection string can be set in the following
>   ways: [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 1. Set the connection string named
>   'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection' in the connectionStrings section of the
>   .config file in the following format , or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 2. Set the environment variable named
>   'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection', or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 3. Set
>   corresponding property of JobHostConfiguration. [12/03/2018 12:10:42]
>   No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods
>   public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers,
>   etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the
>   extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(),
>   config.UseTimers(), etc.). [12/03/2018 12:10:42] Job host started
>   [12/03/2018 12:10:42] The following 1 functions are in error:
>   [12/03/2018 12:10:42] Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error
>   indexing method 'Function1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 'QueueConnection' connection string is
>   missing or empty. The Microsoft Azure Storage account connection
>   string can be set in the following ways: [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 1. Set
>   the connection string named 'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection' in the
>   connectionStrings section of the .config file in the following format
>   , or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 2. Set the environment variable named
>   'AzureWebJobsQueueConnection', or [12/03/2018 12:10:42] 3. Set
>   corresponding property of JobHostConfiguration. [12/03/2018 12:10:42]
>   [12/03/2018 12:10:42] [12/03/2018 12:10:42] Host lock lease acquired
>   by instance ID '000000000000000000000000E37F5049'.

What is the correct implementation of this kind of `Azure Function`? Is there any example on GitHub? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, to try out the servicebus trigger in functions v2 you can reference the nightly build of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` from here https://www.myget.org/feed/azure-appservice/package/nuget/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus

Answer (score 8):

You are confusing Azure Service Bus and Azure Storage Queues. `Queue Trigger` is for Storage Queues, so `Connection` is the connection string for Storage Account and `Path` is for queue path.

To use Service Bus, you should use `Service Bus Trigger`. It takes a bit more effort to setup that one on .NET Core / v2 version of functions, since the Visual Studio tooling is not available for that yet.

I would recommend using Functions v1 for Service Bus for the time being.

`ServiceBusTrigger` is the correct type to use. You should set its `Connection` property to the name of your setting which contains Service Bus connection string, not to connection string itself. Thus

1. Put `ServiceBusTrigger` on your function definition.
2. Add a setting called `MyServiceBusConnection` (or any other name you like). Set it to `sb://myservicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;...`
3. Reference the setting name from the trigger definition, e.g. `[ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "MyServiceBusConnection")]`

Comment: Thanks for your post. To use the v1, in Visual Studio `New Template`, I selected `Azure Function v1` but I don't have `ServiceBusTrigger`. I created it manually: is there another way?

Comment: A template for ServiceBusTrigger should appear if you selected V1. If you can't see it, please make sure you have the latest version of Visual Studio installed and have updated the azure functions tools.

Comment: Note: When creating the project, you won't see a template for a Service Bus Queue Trigger. But if you choose "Empty" and create the project, you can then right click the project in Solution Explorer, Add New Item, choose Azure function, and you'll see the option for Service Bus Queue Trigger

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in a comment that you were having problems finding the service bus queue trigger template, here is what it looks like - as Mikhail mentioned in his answer, fill in the `Connection=""` with the name of the app setting that has your connection string

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

namespace FunctionApp11
{
    public static class Function2
    {
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```